# Нужна ли запятая перед "пока"?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Нужна ли тут запятая:

*"Хочешь получить скидку(,) пока ждешь заказ"?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хочешь получить скидку,  пока ждешь заказ?

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении с придаточным времени, ПОКА ― союз.